# Update value from the drop down list which is a foreign key

Tags: php

im trying to update value of existing data..

[first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HK6r7.png)

[image]

when user click on the edit icon, they will be able to edit the data

[second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWMUI.png)

[image]

they dropdown list are supposed to display the already choosen value. how can i fixed this?

```
<form name="updateform" method="post" action="updateVehicleModel.php">
  <div class="form-group">
    <LABEL>Enter Vehicle Model</LABEL>
    <input  type="hidden" name="modelid" value="<?php if(isset($row['id_vehiclemodel'])) { echo $row['id_vehiclemodel']; } ?>" />
    <input type="text" name="model" value="<?php if(isset($row['vehicle_model'])) { echo $row['vehicle_model']; } ?>" required class="form-control col-md-3 col-sm-3" />
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Choose Vehicle Type</label>
    <input  type="hidden" name="modelid" value="<?php if(isset($row['id_vehiclemodel'])) { echo $row['id_vehiclemodel']; } ?>" />
    <select class="form-control" name="fkvehicleType" value="<?php if(isset($row['id_vehicleType'])){echo $row['vehicle_Type'];}?>">
      <option value="">Select Vehicle Type</option>
      <?php
        $res=mysqli_query($link,"Select * from vehicletype where status_vehicleType='1'");

        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
          ?>
        <option value=<?php echo $row['id_vehicleType'];?>><?php echo $row['vehicle_Type'];?></option>
          <?php
        }

      ?>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Choose Vehicle Brand</label>

    <select class="form-control" name="fkvehicleBrand" value="<?php if(isset($row['id_vehicleBrand'])){echo $row['vehicle_Brand'];}?>">
        <option value="">Select Vehicle Brand</option>
    <?php
        $res=mysqli_query($link,"Select * from vehiclebrand where status_vehicleBrand='1'");

    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
      ?>
    <option value=<?php echo $row['id_vehicleBrand'];?>><?php echo $row['vehicle_Brand'];?></option>
      <?php
    }

    ?>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Choose Status</label>
    <select name="statustype" value="<?php if(isset($row['vehicle_model'])) { echo $row['vehicle_model']; } ?>" required class="form-control">
      <option value="1">Enabled</option>
      <option value="0">Disabled</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-info btn-block" />
  </div>

  <span class="text-success"><?php if (isset($success)) { echo $success; } ?></span>
  <span class="text-danger"><?php if (isset($error)) { echo $error; } ?></span>

</form>
```

Comment: Question should be more clarity. If any user is editing vehicle there should be relationship with user table.
You can use selected=selected by adding condition to make it load previous value.

Comment: @teshvenk thanks. thats exactly what i want. However, im having the same problem on the date. how can i solve this? i means, how can i load the previous date value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved! i used this..thanks for those whose gave me ideas on the solution.

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label>Choose Vehicle Type</label>
     <select class="form-control" name="vehicleType" value="<?php if(isset($row['id_vehicleType'])){echo $row['vehicle_Type'];}?>">
        <option value="">Select Vehicle Type</option>
        <?php 
        $res=mysqli_query($link,"Select * from vehicletype where status_vehicleType='1'");
       while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
         ?>
    <option value=<?php echo $row['id_vehicleType'];?> <?php if($_GET["typeid"]==$row['id_vehicleType']){ ?> selected<?php } ?>><?php echo $row['vehicle_Type'];?></option>
                <?php
                      }
                  ?>
            </select>
        </div>
```